# How can I display my page action on more sites?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing an extension page action that displays an icon in specific URLs, I want to add more than one URL to this page action.

My `background.js` file is this:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (~tab.url.indexOf('URL')) {
        chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
    }
});
```

How do I display my page actions on more sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check for more URLs (and display your page action), then you have two main options:

1. You can use `RegExp`s to check all the links at once, like this:

   ```
   var exp = /(www\.(site1|site2|site3)\.(com|org)/gi;

   if (exp.test(tab.url)) {
       chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
   }
   ```

   and this will work for www.site1.com, www.site2.com, www.site3.com, www.site1.org, etc. For more info check **[Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info)**.
2. Check your string using a for loop and an `Array` that contains all the URLs, like this:

   ```
   var urls = [
       "site1",
       "site2",
       "site3",
       ...
   ];

   for (var i=0; i < urls.length; i++)
       if (~tab.url.indexOf(urls[i])) {
           chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
           break;
       }
   ```

These are not the only options you have, another one might be to check with more than one `if (...)`, but it's a bit heavy to write down.

Comment: Marco I duplicated the code just do not know if it's way is correct, it is working, an I use this?

Comment: @guto duplicating the code is the worst thing you can do, because it will slow down your extension adding more listeners to the same event that will fire altogether and do things that you can easily do with only one of them.